# Did the Voice of America become more critical of the US after the end of the Cold War?

Tags: united-states, government, media

In a [speech](https://youtu.be/o20xN8cMxsU?t=102) given to Voice of America (VOA) staff towards the end of the Trump presidency, Mike Pompeo (who was Secretary of State at the time) stated that after the end of the Cold War VOA (like similar US government-financed posts) had made a turn towards being too critical of the US, even [joking](https://youtu.be/o20xN8cMxsU?t=67) that the network had become something like the "vice of America" by paying too much attention to negative news from the US.

Can this change in focus/bias after the Cold War be substantiated with some kind of [quantitative contents analysis](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.5172/rsj.11.3.181?journalCode=rrso20) of VOA reporting during and after the Cold War?